# Possible to have duplicate usernames on different two multisites

Tags: multisite, users, user-registration

I have a multisite set up with two sites setup:

```
example.com/site01
example.com/site02
```

With both sites, they are using the same custom theme which generates a default list of users (`publisher01`, `publisher02`, ..., `publisher10`)

However, when I activate the theme on the second site, the users don't get generated due to the fact of having the same usernames.

Is it possible to have the same list of users (but not the same user) in each site apart of the network?

The only way I can think of is to have it unique Wordpress installs, and not apart of the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, No.

Because WordPress Multisite stores all users in one table, you can't have two user on two sites in network with the same username.

Read more at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Multisite_Table_Overview